# Output bottom line in Powershell

Tags: windows, powershell

I want to output the last entry of `Get-Hotfix` in PowerShell. How does it work?

Example:

```
Source        Description      HotFixID      InstalledBy          InstalledOn              
------        -----------      --------      -----------          -----------              
DESKTOP-FU... Update           KB5010472     NT-AUTORITÄT\SYSTEM  15.03.2022 00:00:00      
DESKTOP-FU... Update           KB5003791                          06.10.2021 00:00:00      
DESKTOP-FU... Security Update  KB5011487     NT-AUTORITÄT\SYSTEM  14.03.2022 00:00:00      
DESKTOP-FU... Update           KB5007273     NT-AUTORITÄT\SYSTEM  02.01.2022 00:00:00      
DESKTOP-FU... Security Update  KB5011352     NT-AUTORITÄT\SYSTEM  09.02.2022 00:00:00      
DESKTOP-FU... Security Update  KB5005699                          06.10.2021 00:00:00
```

I want to output the `KB5005699` update to the console.

Comment: Stackoverflow is a Q&A site devoted to programming questions, your question seems to be about general computer software problems, so you might want to ask it over at [Superuser](https://superuser.com/) instead.

Comment: https://www.educba.com/powershell-tail/

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Select-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object?view=powershell-7.2) with the `-Last 1` parameter to get the last object and `-ExpandProperty HotFixID` to get the Value of the `HotFixID` property:

```
Get-HotFix | Select-Object -Last 1 -ExpandProperty HotFixID
```

Another alternative would be to get the last object by the [`-1` index](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_arrays?view=powershell-7.2#accessing-and-using-array-elements) and use dot notation `.HotFixID` to get the Value:

```
(Get-HotFix)[-1].HotFixID
```